# How to vstack efficiently a sequence of large numpy array chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am generating a sequence of numpy arrays as follows:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

for i in chunker(X,10000):
    e = function(i)
    print('new marix',e)

new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
...
new matrix (10000, 3208)
```

I would like to [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) the above `n` matrices in a single one. Thus, I tried the following:

```
    X = np.vstack(e)
```

However, when I print `X` I am getting again:

```
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
new matrix (10000, 3208)
...
new matrix (10000, 3208)
```

Instead of a new vstacked single matrix. Any idea of how to vstack this sequence of numpy arrays?.

**Update**

From jedward's answer I edited my code as follows:

import numpy as np

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

for (r,i) in enumerate(chunker(X,10000)):
    e = function(i)
    print('new matrix',e)
    X[r,:] = e

print(X)
```

Comment: The input to `vstack` is supposed to be a list of arrays with a matching last dimension.  `e` doesn't look like that.  You need to collect the individual `e` into a list.

Comment: In your loop, what's the shape of `e`?  Of `X`?  `X[r,:]`?

Comment: X.shape = (878049, 3208), e.shape = (10000, 3208), merged[r,:].shape = (3208,). The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. Thanks for the help @hpaulj! I am also getting: `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

Comment: `e` has to be put into a `chunk` sized slot in `X`, not just one row.  I'd suggest testing on a smaller test case.

Answer (score 3):

One way, although probably not the most efficient, would be to create a list of the lists you want to stack, then stack once, outside the loop.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

# Some fake function (n.b. this is a silly way to reverse a list)
def function(arr):
    arr.reverse()
    return arr

# Generate fake X
X = list(range(100))

chunks = []
for i in chunker(X,10):
    e = function(i)
    print('new matrix',e)
    chunks.append(e)

merged = np.vstack(chunks)
print(merged)
```

Output:

```
new matrix [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
new matrix [19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
new matrix [29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20]
new matrix [39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30]
new matrix [49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40]
new matrix [59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50]
new matrix [69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60]
new matrix [79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70]
new matrix [89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80]
new matrix [99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90]
[[ 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0]
 [19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10]
 [29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20]
 [39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30]
 [49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40]
 [59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50]
 [69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 60]
 [79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70]
 [89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80]
 [99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90]]
```

Or *not* creating an intermediate list:

```
merged = np.zeros([0,10])
for i in chunker(X,10):
    e = function(i)
    print('new matrix',e)
    merged = np.vstack([merged, e])

print(merged)
```

But the most efficient would be to initialize a numpy array prior to the loop, and then set rows of that array inside the loop.  You'd need to calculate the dimensions of the final `merged` array first (here I just created it as a 10x10 matrix, because I knew the size).

```
merged = np.zeros([10,10])
for (r,i) in enumerate(chunker(X,10)):
    e = function(i)
    print('new matrix',e)
    merged[r,:] = e

print(merged)
```

Comment: These are very large arrays, is there a more efficient way of doing this?.

Comment: I added two additional options.  The bottom is by far the most efficient.

Comment: I got this exception: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100) into shape (3208)` any idea of how to proceed?... thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll need to change this line `merged = np.zeros([10,10])` to match the rows and columns of your final, merged, array.  From your error, the product of these two numbers should be at least 3208.  And the second number in `[10,10]` should probably match the second argument you're passing to `chunker` (in the code you posted, that's 10.  So you might write: `merged = np.zeros([321,10])`

Comment: I see, thanks now I got: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10000,3208) into shape (3208)` again , any idea of what to do?

Comment: Can you edit into your question the code that you have now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118724/discussion-between-john-doe-and-jedwards).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a very efficient way of doing this without resorting to cython, numba, or friends.

Perhaps the lightest on memory might be doing something like the following (not sure about this):

```py
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

large_array = reduce(lambda a1, a2: np.vstack([a1,a2]), array_iterable)
```

That said, it seems like you know your resulting array size, so it will be more efficient to generate an empty array and fill with your follows with the chunk method

```
large_array = np.zeros((1000,1000,3208))

for i in chunker(X, 1000):
    large_array[i,:,:] = function(i)
```

Which you could further speed up with [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html), with greater improvements the heavier the cpu/IO load present in `function()`.